# How to create rule repository and load it with some checklist rule in sonarqube 4.3?

Tags: sonarqube

I am building a language plugin for sonarqube version 4.3. Currently I am unabl to add new repository for rules.

In previous version there was AnnotationRuleParserto parse the rules. what is in version 4.3 ?

please tell me how to create a new repository and add rules to it in  sonarqube version 4.3 .

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [RulesDefinitions](http://docs.sonarsource.org/latest/apidocs/org/sonar/api/server/rule/RulesDefinition.html). If rules are declared in a XML file with the standard SonarQube format (see [RulesDefinitionXmlLoader](http://docs.sonarsource.org/latest/apidocs/org/sonar/api/server/rule/RulesDefinitionXmlLoader.html)), then it can be loaded by using :

```
public class MyJsRulesDefinition implements RulesDefinition {

   private final RulesDefinitionXmlLoader xmlLoader;

   public MyJsRulesDefinition(RulesDefinitionXmlLoader xmlLoader) {
     this.xmlLoader = xmlLoader;
   }

   @Override
   public void define(Context context) {
     NewRepository repository = context.createRepository("my_js", "js").setName("My Javascript Analyzer");
     // see javadoc of RulesDefinitionXmlLoader for the format
     xmlLoader.load(repository, getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/rules.xml"));
     repository.done();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the approach suggested by L. Langó is the way to go. I personally used it too on a plugin I'm developing. Just to clarify about the mandatory required structure of the .xml file containing the rules:

```
<rules>
    <rule>
        <key> </key>
        <name> </name>
        <description> </description>
    </rule>
</rules>
```